# Ошибка при включении Windows 7 SP1: "mfc100u.dll is missing"

Tags: windows

При включении компьютера вылазит окно с ошибкой. Скрин ниже:[image: снимок]Подскажите, как избавиться от этой ошибки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычно это сообщение выскакивает, когда установлено приложение, которому не хватает C++ рантайма. В вашем случае это, видимо, NBAgent.exe. Исправляется так:

1. система грузится в безопасный режим,
2. устанавливается [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5555) (или другой подходящий),
3. система перегружается в обычный режим.